# Adding progress bar for reading a dataframe using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to create a progress bar that could show progress while reading a very huge CSV file. I am creating a pandas data frame that reads a CSV file over the network. Since the CSV has lots of data so my program will just be stuck when it is processing it so I wanted to have a progress bar that could give the status as how much processing is done. Is it feasible to have a progress bar to track this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with implementing a progress bar when reading a file is that the only way to do it cheaply is to keep track of the bytes that have been read and compare them to the size of the file. You have no way of knowing how many lines are in the CSV without fully reading it. Whichever way you do it, it has a performance penalty.

You could iterate through the lines in the file, count their size and then append the line to a dict. Appending to a DataFrame has a significant performance hit so you're better off storing the dict in memory and then creating a DataFrame at the end.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import csv

filepath = 'path_to_file'
file_size = os.path.getsize(filepath)
BAR_SIZE = 40


with open(filepath) as f:
    my_dict={}
    processed = 0
    csv_file = csv.reader(f, quotechar='"')
    for row, line in enumerate(csv_file):
        processed += sum(len(col) for col in line) + len(line) - 1
        if row == 0:
            columns = line
            for col in columns:
                my_dict[col] = []
            continue
        bars = int(processed/file_size * BAR_SIZE)
        for col, value in enumerate(line):
            my_dict[columns[col]].append(value)
        print('[', u"\u2588"*bars, ' '*(BAR_SIZE-bars-1), ']', end='\r', sep='')
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict)
```

The faster way to read the file would be to use chunking in the read_csv function of pandas, but only if you know the number of lines in the file.